# xml parsing in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a requirement where in I have to parse the xml to get the desired fields, perform operations on the desired field and generate a csv using the data.

I looked at XmlLoader available in pig, however it seems to return the xml tags as well.
What I am interested in is the data. Is there any way I can achieve this?
I also need to generate a CSV using the data.

Any working samples would be of great help.

Comment: How nested / hierarchical is your XML, can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEX_EXTRACT() to get the information out of the tags, possibbly SUBSTRING() and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL as well.

Answer (score 0):

piggybank jar provides xml loader in pig

In the load statement of pig you need to load using XMLLoader. Where you need to mention your parent tag properly.

```
A = load '/path of the file' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('parent_tag') as (x:chararray);
B = foreach A generate REPLACE(x,'[\\n]','') as x;
```

After this you need to use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL to extract the data in between the tags

```
C = foreach B generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'.*(?:<child_tag1>)([^<]*).*(?:<child_tag2>)([^<]*).*');
```

For more details you can refer to the below link

https://acadgild.com/blog/converting-xml-into-csv-using-pig/